# Android setlistAdapter error

Tags: android

hi just getting an error and I'm not sure why can anyone help?

this is how my json feed is structured i want the news array

{"code":200,"error":null,"data":{"news":[{"news_id":"8086"
I'm getting an error here: in the oneOjectsItem

setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_item, oneObjectsItem));

here my code

```
        // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);



        JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("news");


        for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Pulling items from the array
            String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("title");



        }


    } catch(Exception e){
        // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, oneObjectsItem)); 



ListView list = getListView();
list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(),1000).show();
    }



});

}
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Please give the logs if you are getting an error. Or, is it loading the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Use setListAdapter after initiliazing the list element. You can find a detailed sample [here.](http://tugrulasik.com/2011/12/21/android-not-defteri-uygulamasi/)

Comment: Its got the oneObjectsItemUnderlined in red and when click it tells me to create field. But this doesnt work either